# How do you Manage a CountdownTimer from within an IntentService?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-service

I am implementing a Pomodoro Timer using an IntentService and I seem to be struggling with managing a timer within an IntentService . What I have at the moment is the following:

**The code:**

```
package com.nursson.pomodorotimer.service;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.nursson.pomodorotimer.model.Pomodoro;

/**
 * An {@link IntentService} subclass for handling asynchronous task requests in
 * a service on a separate handler thread.
 * <p/>
 * helper methods.
 */
public class PomodoroService extends IntentService {

    public static final String ACTION_CANCELLED = "com.nursson.pomodorotimer.service.pomodoro.action.CANCELLED";
    public static final String ACTION_COMPLETE = "com.nursson.pomodorotimer.service.pomodoro.action.COMPLETE";
    public static final String ACTION_START = "com.nursson.pomodorotimer.service.pomodoro.action.START";
    public static final String ACTION_STOP = "com.nursson.pomodorotimer.service.pomodoro.action.STOP";
    public static final String ACTION_TICK = "com.nursson.pomodorotimer.service.pomodoro.action.TICK";

    public static final String EXTRA_TIME_REMAINING = "com.nursson.pomodorotimer.service.pomodoro.param.TIME_REMAINING";

    private boolean started;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Intent tickIntent = new Intent(ACTION_TICK);
            tickIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME_REMAINING, millisUntilFinished);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(PomodoroService.this).sendBroadcast(tickIntent);
            Log.i("TIMER", "ticking...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            started = false;
            Intent tickIntent = new Intent(ACTION_COMPLETE);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(PomodoroService.this).sendBroadcast(tickIntent);
            Log.i("TIMER", "countdown Finished()");
            Looper.myLooper().quit();
        }
    };

    public PomodoroService() {
        super("PomodoroService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("TIMER", "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        Log.i("TIMER", "onDestroy()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (intent == null) {
            return;
        }

        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case ACTION_START:
                handleStartAction();
                break;
            case ACTION_STOP:
                handleStopAction();
                break;
        }

        Looper.loop();
    }

    private void handleStopAction() {
        Log.i("TIMER", "handleStopAction(): " + started);
        if (started) {
            Log.i("TIMER", "handleStopAction() - Cancel Timer");
            started = false;
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            Intent tickIntent = new Intent(ACTION_CANCELLED);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(PomodoroService.this).sendBroadcast(tickIntent);
        }
    }

    private void handleStartAction() {
        Log.i("TIMER", "handleStartAction()"  + started);
        if (!started) {
            Log.i("TIMER", "handleStartAction() - Starting Timer");
            started = true;
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
    }

    boolean isStarted() {
        return started;
    }

    CountDownTimer getCountDownTimer() {
        return countDownTimer;
    }
}
```

**What is happening in the code**

So this is basically an IntentService that contains a CountdownTimer to broadcast messages to activities. It also uses `Looper.loop();` and `Looper.myLooper().quit();` to try and manage the lifecycle. If I do not include this then `onDestroy()` gets called and the CountdownTimer runs until the end. I want `onDestroy()` to be called after the timer finishes

The exception that I am getting is when the code reaches `Looper.myLooper().quit();`, which is the stacktrace below:

```
08-29 02:27:38.855 3337-3337/com.nursson.pomodorotimer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.nursson.pomodorotimer, PID: 3337
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Main thread not allowed to quit.
                                                                             at android.os.MessageQueue.quit(MessageQueue.java:415)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.quit(Looper.java:228)
                                                                             at com.nursson.pomodorotimer.service.PomodoroService$1$override.onFinish(PomodoroService.java:44)
                                                                             at com.nursson.pomodorotimer.service.PomodoroService$1$override.access$dispatch(PomodoroService.java)
                                                                             at com.nursson.pomodorotimer.service.PomodoroService$1.onFinish(PomodoroService.java:0)
                                                                             at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**What I want to happen**

I want to be able to start and stop a CountDownTimer using an IntentService and also to be a "good citizen" when doing this.

The end goal is to have a timer that can last through orientation change and can continue running when the activity is terminated.

**What I tried so far:**

- Removing `Looper.myLooper().quit();`. Then `onDestroy()` never gets called when the CountDownTimer is done.
- Removing any `Looper` references. Then `onDestroy()` gets called too early. The timer works but then I cannot get a reference to CountDownTimer to cancel it.

**What I thought about:**

- There is an alternative to a CountDownTimer that is better suited to what I want to do? An AlarmManager maybe?
- Should I be using Service instead of IntentService which might make it easier to handle the CountDownTimer?

Comment: Better to use Service instead of IntentService if you have things like CountDownTimer, TimerTask etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All examples of `Looper` that I have seen use this pattern

```
Looper.prepare();
// create a handler
Looper.loop();
```

It creates and runs a message loop for threads that do not have one, the handler is being used to interact with the loop.

Now in your code I do not see neither `prepare` nor `Handler`, so first you do not follow the typical pattern and besides misuse the blocking character of `Looper.loop()` to prevent the `onHandleIntent` from termination.

Calling `Looper.myLooper().quit()` in `onFinish` is not working since `CountDownTimer` methods seem to run on the main thread, so you are trying to quit the main thread's message loop. It looks like it doesn't like it.

If you only need to block the `onHandleIndent` until `onFinish` gets executed, why not use one of plain Java threading patterns? Like

```
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private final Condition waitForFinish = lock.newCondition();

@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (intent == null) {
        return;
    }

    switch (intent.getAction()) {
        case ACTION_START:
            handleStartAction();
            break;
        case ACTION_STOP:
            handleStopAction();
            break;
    }
    lock.lock();
    try {
        while (started) {
            waitForFinish.await();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        // log exceptions
    } finally {
       lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    started = false;
    Intent tickIntent = new Intent(ACTION_COMPLETE);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(PomodoroService.this).sendBroadcast(tickIntent);
    Log.i("TIMER", "countdown Finished()");
    lock.lock();
    try {
        waitForFinish.signal();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The disadvantage – IntentService handles requests in a single worker thread, so as long as it blocks in `onHandleIntent` it won’t accept new requests, like a request to stop the timer (better check this than believe me - I do not have an android SDK here to proove it).

An alternative solution would be to put the blocking call into `onDestroy` - it would free `onHandleIntent` for new requests and prevent the service from finishing until the timer is done.

Or use another type of service – bound or unbound, which won’t destroy itself after being out of work. They have their downside though – both are not meant to do work off the main thread, this is what IntentService is for.

Comment: (not sure why I can't @reference you?) Thanks for the info on CountDownTimer and the main thread! One question on other types of services. Would a bound or unbound be able to last even after the application is terminated, or would I need to rely on a foreground service?

Comment: Bound services usually last between `bind` and `unbind`, can be bound from multiple applications and are destroyed when the last application unbinds (except when started by `startService`). Now application should rather unbind services they had previously bound to not waste resources, so it means a bound service typically relies on the client.

Comment: Unbound service is started by `startService` and stopped either by `stopService` (from outside) or by calling `stopSelf` by itself. It can last beyond the life time of the client.